# Hscan all items in a set of keys

Tags: search, redis

Assuming I have the following hashes:

```
item:1 - field "a"
item:2 - field "b"
item:3 - field "a"
```

and a set called 'items' that stores the above hashes' keys as such:

items:

```
item:1
item:2
item:3
```

How could I go through each item in the items set to find all items with a field that equals "a"?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do that - a scan is expensive and requires time.

What you want to do is to keep a Set with the items that interest you, e.g. `items:b` would contain `item:1` and `item:2`. This Set, which is essentially an index, will allow you to fetch the items with a "b" field efficiently.